I have to write the whole pattern in one single loop but I can't figure out the approach or how should I start and develop the whole thing

Write a single loop (using c) to print the following: (In each > pass you should print only one character):
aA
aabC
aaabb*E
aaaabbb**G
aaaaabbbb***I
aaaaaabbbbb****K


The problem is I have to do the whole thing in one single loop and can't use an array. I can't figure out the approach of doing it.

Pick a language. Is that the verbatim instructions? Hardcode the strings and print them one character at a time.

You have to print 52 visible characters and 6 newlines.  You're supposed to print one character per iteration.  So, you will have a loop from 1 to 58 and will have to calculate (tediously) which character to print on this iteration.  It won't be pretty.

It’s not clear from the description…are the * characters literal characters are do they represent the continuation of some pattern? Also not clear why this is tagged python.

I am allowed to use if else statements  only but how do I use them

There are many ways to do this. Here is one:
    int row = 0;
    int col = 0;
    char c;
    while (row < 6) {
        c = col <= row     ? 'a'
          : col <= row * 2 ? 'b'
          : col <  row * 3 ? '*'
          : col == (row == 0) + row * 3 ? 'A' + 2*row
          : '\n';
        putchar(c);
        col++;
        if (c == '\n') {
            col = 0;
            row++;
        }
    }

Obviously you can skip finding a logic in the required output and just write 58 if statements:
    char c;
    for (int i = 0; i < 58; i++) {
        if (i == 0) c = 'a';
        if (i == 1) c = 'A';
        if (i == 2) c = '\n';
        if (i == 3) c = 'a';
        if (i == 4) c = 'a';
        if (i == 5) c = 'b';
        if (i == 6) c = 'C';
        if (i == 7) c = '\n';
        if (i == 8) c = 'a';
        if (i == 9) c = 'a';
        if (i == 10) c = 'a';
        if (i == 11) c = 'b';
        if (i == 12) c = 'b';
        if (i == 13) c = '*';
        if (i == 14) c = 'E';
        if (i == 15) c = '\n';
        if (i == 16) c = 'a';
        if (i == 17) c = 'a';
        if (i == 18) c = 'a';
        if (i == 19) c = 'a';
        if (i == 20) c = 'b';
        if (i == 21) c = 'b';
        if (i == 22) c = 'b';
        if (i == 23) c = '*';
        if (i == 24) c = '*';
        if (i == 25) c = 'G';
        if (i == 26) c = '\n';
        if (i == 27) c = 'a';
        if (i == 17) c = 'a';
        if (i == 18) c = 'a';
        if (i == 19) c = 'a';
        if (i == 20) c = 'b';
        if (i == 21) c = 'b';
        if (i == 22) c = 'b';
        if (i == 23) c = '*';
        if (i == 24) c = '*';
        if (i == 25) c = 'G';
        if (i == 26) c = '\n';
        if (i == 27) c = 'a';
        if (i == 28) c = 'a';
        if (i == 29) c = 'a';
        if (i == 30) c = 'a';
        if (i == 31) c = 'a';
        if (i == 32) c = 'b';
        if (i == 33) c = 'b';
        if (i == 34) c = 'b';
        if (i == 35) c = 'b';
        if (i == 36) c = '*';
        if (i == 37) c = '*';
        if (i == 38) c = '*';
        if (i == 39) c = 'I';
        if (i == 40) c = '\n';
        if (i == 41) c = 'a';
        if (i == 42) c = 'a';
        if (i == 43) c = 'a';
        if (i == 44) c = 'a';
        if (i == 45) c = 'a';
        if (i == 46) c = 'a';
        if (i == 47) c = 'b';
        if (i == 48) c = 'b';
        if (i == 49) c = 'b';
        if (i == 50) c = 'b';
        if (i == 51) c = 'b';
        if (i == 52) c = '*';
        if (i == 53) c = '*';
        if (i == 54) c = '*';
        if (i == 55) c = '*';
        if (i == 56) c = 'K';
        if (i == 57) c = '\n';
        putchar(c);
    }


The usefulness of this depends a little bit on whether the OP gets asked to subsequently scale this to larger output. Hopefully not, as this seems more like an exercise in math than programming.

@Chris, I agree. But this scales up to row < 13, when the last line ends with "Y". What would have to happen after that is subject to interpretation. There is some very basic "math" in the conditions that appear in the expression assigned to c.

I'm a sucker for a nice nested ternary.
